# Updating Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.10 Failed

Tags: upgrade

I tried to upgrade from 14.04 to 15.10 and everything crashed. Nothing is working D:

```
Sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It's not working!!

Comment: There is no supported direct upgrade path from 14.04 to 15.10.  You will have to go through 14.10 and 15.04 or wait until 16.04 is released, which will offer a direct upgrade path from 14.04 to 16.04. Moreover, the commands you are mentioning are not the right commands to perform a distro upgrade.  Read this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

since i can not comment yet, you should try this, first open up your /etc/apt/sources.list and change all trusty links to wily
then indeed do apt-get update;apt-get upgrade and apt-get -f install, maybe it works? please post your results!